# maintain list of active users and retrieve it on the webhost

Tags: php, mysql

first - I'm absolute beginner with web back-end stuff!

I'm looking for the most simple way to achieve the following:

1. on the web-host: maintain a user list (doesn't have to be persistent,
   if the server is rebooted)
2. allow a client to add it's name to the user list
3. allow a client to receive the user list

my clients are flash-players but this doesn't really matter.
if my web-host would support running servlets, i would create a simple java socket-server - but my web-host allows only PHP and MySQL databases.

Is it possible to do this with php only without the use of a MySQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the webhost has [ACP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) installed, you can use it to keep the list in memory between page invocations:

```
apc_store("userlist", new ArrayObject($active_user_list), $ttl);


$temp = apc_get("userlist");
if (isset($temp) && $temp !== false) {
    return $temp->getArrayCopy();
}
return null;
```

If no PHP cache is not installed, you will need to write the user list to a mysql table.